# trouble installing flycheck

Tags: flycheck

Hi I am new to emacs and  am having trouble installing flycheck.

I have modified my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file to:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA Stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("gnu"."http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))

(packages-initialize)

(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

and when I try and  install flycheck with
`M-x package-install RET flycheck RET`

I get as far as `M-x package-install RET flycheck` - and I am asked to complete flycheck with a `-option`.

If I list the packages there are several `flycheck -apertium`, `flycheck-cask` but there isn’t one for just flycheck.

I would like to use flycheck with syntax checking for php. As far as I understood I would need to install flycheck (not flycheck- some option) then phpcli.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you do `M-x list-packages`?  Do you see the "flycheck" package there (you should do) and what status does it have?  Perhaps it's already been installed as a dependency for something else which is why you don't get it as an option to install using `M-x package-install`.  Also once installed I don't think you'll need an additional Emacs package for checking PHP, just whatever external tools the checker needs.

Comment: Hi stevoooo @stevoooo Thanks for the comment, I see a list of flycheck packages e.g. flycheck-apertium, flycheck-cask through to flycheck-ycmd.  I think I was expecting a package called flycheck only, but maybe I have just misunderstood.  The website says install flycheck and then in the quick start section install the syntax checker required for the particular language you want to use, which for php I think is phpcli.

Comment: There is a package simply called "flycheck", and I was wondering whether you see it when you do `list-packages`. I've got "flycheck           20170707.920  available  melpa      On-the-fly syntax checking" and "flycheck           20170524.1742 dependency            On-the-fly syntax checking".

Comment: sounds like you need to do `M-x package-refresh-package` first to refresh the list of packages

Comment: Right I have got it, it was as installed after all, it just wasn't enabled.  By using M-x global-flycheck-mode I enabled it and now it is functioning correctly.  I had assumed the line in the init file would enable it automatically. It is working now though so thanks alot for your help.